# How do I loop the current_playback() function from Spotipy?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to implement Spotify's API in a TKinter GUI so I can make some sort of player (display current song info, artist(s) name, album name, control playback, etc.). I managed to get the info I need using `sp.current_playback()`, but I need it to update every so often (say, when I skip to the next song).

Every loop method I've tried so far (`while True`, `if __name__ == '__main__':`, `for in`) has failed me.

I've also managed to make the TKinter label update, so that's not a problem. The only thing I can't get right is to get the `np = sp.current_playback()` variable to update from time to time so the TKinter label also changes.

My code currently looks like this:

```
# [Credentials/Auth/Scope/Token]
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token, client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
user = sp.user('username')

def np1():
    nowp = sp.current_playback(market="BR")
    return nowp
np = np1()

def getalbum(): 
    godown = np.get('item').get('album').get('name')
    return godown

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np1()
    getalbum()
    print(getalbum())
```

(I've omitted unimportant code)

Comment: How is this related to `tkinter`?.

Comment: Also `if __name__ == "__main__"` isn't a loop. It only runs 1 time if it is the main file